# Reserving Space for QScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a QScrollArea with a custom QWidget. The problem I am facing is that whenever the scrollbar appears, it leads to shifting of elements in the widget. So, I want to reserve some space, so when the scrollbar appears or disappears, the widget is not affected. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about myScrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn) and myScrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and just solved it(might not completely).

I set a fixed width for scroll widget and QScrollArea, and set QScrollArea Horizontal SizePolicy fixed, and hide HorizontalScrollBar.
Sample code

```
QWidget *pWidget = new QWidget(this);
pWidget->setFixedWidth(500);
pWidget->setLayout(...)

QScrollArea *pScrollArea = new QScrollArea();
// Same with widget
pScrollArea->setFixedWidth(500);
pScrollArea->setWidget(pWidget);
pScrollArea->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
// Needed.
pScrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

I also find a Bugreport: [QTBUG-2347
QScrollArea: a new scroll policy that reserves space for the scroll bar](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-2347), and it is closed. But I don't know whether the bug is fixed and what's the solution.